# Can't trigger action of a UIButton after modifying its UI

Tags: swift, ibaction, iphone-x

I create a UIButton which is displayed inside a XIB. But when I add a modification for the iPhone X display, I can't trigger the method inside its action. Here is the code below:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tryAgainButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func tryAgainButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    myFunction()
}

    if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone, // Iphone X
        UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 2436 {
        label.font = label.font.withSize(12)
        contentView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
            make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(-20)
            containerView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
            contentView.backgroundColor? = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
            containerView.backgroundColor? = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
            label.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
            helpButton.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
            tryAgainButton.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
            let underlineAttributes : [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
                NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle : NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,
                NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
            ]

            let helpButtonAttributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Help",
                                                                      attributes: underlineAttributes)

            let tryAgainButtonAttributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Try Again",
                                                                          attributes: underlineAttributes)

            helpButton.setAttributedTitle(helpButtonAttributeString, for: .normal)
            tryAgainButton.setAttributedTitle(tryAgainButtonAttributeString, for: .normal)

        }
    }
```

`myFunction()` is not reachable when I run with an Iphone X.

Comment: Your `button` probably is outside of its `superView`. Could you please check after setting `button.superview!.clipsToBounds = true` if `button` is visible or not?

Comment: Just going by the code posted - the *entire* if statement starting with  `if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone` is *completely* outside of, well, anything. Please, if this is a typo, correct it.

Comment: Yes it's still visible.

Comment: @dfd Thats why I rejected the `MRFrhn` 's edit but don't know why it has been approved. :)

Comment: Also, just to be sure you aren't making a newbie mistake (thinking it's iPhone X but it's really something else) make sure your `@IBAction` is actually triggering code. One last suggestion, use breakpoints (provided this if statement is being hit) to see exactly what is failing.

Comment: @TheTiger, I'm not seeing where the edit changes anything with regards to getting the if statement executed. (It's probably my blindness but who knows. Assuming that it is part of a missing line `func myFunction()` I'm suggesting (1) making sure it's actually getting hit and (2) am wondering why `userInterfaceIdiom == .phone` means *"iPhone X"*. The implied question is this is related to iPhone X **only**, but I'm guessing it's *at least* related to all iPhones.

Comment: @dfd Yes edit changed, The if statement part was separate with ///... and now it just mixed up with the whole code as you can see. The OP was posted it separately to showing how he modified the code for `iPhoneX`. Although its not related to issue but with edit.

Comment: @Blisko Could you please attach the screenshot of button's screen?

Comment: https://zupimages.net/up/18/18/q07f.png
The button is inside a banner

Comment: Is it clickable if you remove the code posted by you? Or is it clickable on other devices? I don't see anything in above code which will effect the button's click event... problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Yes it works perfectly with other devices.

Comment: If button is inside the banner check same thing for `banners.superview!.clipsToBounds = true` ... or if banner is added on another view check for that view too. Your button is probably outside of its parent views. Just check for all. Set the background color of each view then see.

Comment: I set contentView.superview?.clipsToBounds = true and all the buttons are not visible any more.

Comment: @Blisko And your buttons are added on `contentView` or one of its subviews then it should not be. So you will have to set the right frame to buttons or `contentView`.

Comment: self.view.layoutIfNeeded(). I believe your button's frame is not exactly where you are seeing in on screen.